# Convert a curl command to powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

I would like to convert a command to generate a masterkey from curl to PowerShell but I never did things like that before..
The objective is to access to an ovea Api but first I have to generate a masterkey.
Here is the curl command (tested on centos and works):

```
curl -L -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic Yw...=' -X POST https://dnsadmin.test.com/apikeys --data '{"description": "masterkey","domains":["testapi.com"], "role": "User"}'
```

And here is what I tried:

```
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add = ("Authorization",'Basic Yw...=')
$headers.Add {-description = "masterkey","domains" ["testapi.com"], "role": "User"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://dnsadmin.test.com/apikeys -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
```

If any of you have an idea I would take it thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `--data` with `curl` it is sent as the body of the request. In the Powershell example you're trying to do some stuff with the header that doesn't make sense.

This would be the equivalent to your `curl` command:

```bsh
$headers = @{
  Authorization = 'Basic Yw...='
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://dnsadmin.test.com/apikeys -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body '{"description": "masterkey","domains":["testapi.com"], "role": "User"}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense, but now I have this error: `Invoke-RestMethod : {"msg": "Unauthorized"}
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://dnsadmin.test.com/apikeys
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand`

Comment: That's because the web server returned a 401 Unauthorized. Are you sure you entered your correct Authorization header into my example?

Comment: I used this function to encode my id and password : `$Text = ‘myid:mypswd’
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Text)
$EncodedText =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$EncodedText ` Do you think it can be the problem ? I'm sure to have entered the correct Authorization

Comment: As long as the resulting header is exactly the same as the example used with curl that should be fine. There are two things you can try: 1. change the call to Invoke-WebRequest instead of Invoke-RestMethod. 2. Download Fiddler and inspect the http calls that are made by both those requests (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and see what differs

Comment: Ok it works! the probleme was with the encode function I tried with this one `[string]$sStringToEncode="My string to encode"
$sEncodedString=[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($sStringToEncode))
write-host "Encoded String:" $sEncodedString`  credit: [link](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-encode-and-decode-base64-strings/) Thank you a lot for your help @Cbsch